# My menu and heading move when I resize page, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to finish off my menu and headings, however, when I resize the browser window my menu and my headings move to the right and will not center or stay where I want it too. Any help would be much appreciated. HTML and CSS below.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

body {
  min-width: 100px;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00)
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: fixed;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 339px;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

h3,
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 100% "Verdana", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 339px
}

ul {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a,
li,
h2,
h3,
p {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1.00)
}

img {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

li {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

img {
  width: inherit;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: inherit;
  object-fit: contain;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}


/* drop down menu */

.clearfix:after {
  display: inherit;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu {
  width: 720px;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin-left: 259px;
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.menu li:hover>a,
.menu .current-item>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 0%;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #DCDADA;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 2;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 171px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
  height: 349px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water Project">
            <title>Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Xavier website styles.css">
    </head>

<body>
        <div>
        <header>
        <h1><a href="../../Xavier home:portfolio page.html">Xavier King</a></h1>
   </header>

        <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
          <li><a href="../../Xavier home:portfolio page.html">Portfolio&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li>
                <a>Projects <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>&nbsp;<ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="../freedom/freedom.html">Are We Free?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Ben Hart/Ben Hart.html">Ben Hart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Daisy Bertenshaw/Daisy Bertenshaw.html">Daisy Bertenshaw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Decay/Decay.html">Decay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Earth Wind FIre and Water/Earth, Wind, FIre and Water.html">Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Frozen In Time/Frozen In Time.html">Frozen In Time</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../The CCTV's Eye/The CCTV's Eye.html">The CCTV's Eye</a></li>
              </ul>&nbsp;<li><a href="../../Xavier CV page.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CV&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="../../Xavier contact info page.html">&nbsp;Contact</a></li>&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
    <h2>Earth, Wind, Fire, Water</h2>

        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r air.jpg" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Air" />
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y air.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Air"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r air.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Air"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Fire"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Fire"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Fire"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
.menu {
  width: 720px;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This way, it centers the `.menu` in a similar way such as `text-align: center`.

```js
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 2000);
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0, auto;
}

body {
  min-width: 100px;
}

body {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00)
}

body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

h2,
h3 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.3em;
  text-align: fixed;
  margin-right: 600px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 339px;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

h3,
p {
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: 100% "Verdana", sans-serif;
  margin-left: 339px
}

ul {
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}

a,
li,
h2,
h3,
p {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(128, 128, 128, 1.00)
}

img {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

li {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

header {
  margin-top: 0px;
}

menu {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

img {
  width: inherit;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: inherit;
  object-fit: contain;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

.menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}


/* drop down menu */

.clearfix:after {
  display: inherit;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.menu {
  width: 720px;
  min-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto; /*-------------- This code ------------*/
}

.menu li {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  font-family: "Verdana", sans-serif;
}

.menu a {
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.menu li:hover>a,
.menu .current-item>a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.menu .arrow {
  font-size: .5em;
  line-height: 0%;
}

.menu>ul>li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 19px;
}

.menu>ul>li>a {
  padding: 10px 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menu>ul>li:hover>a,
.menu>ul>.current-item>a {
  background: #DCDADA;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu {
  z-index: 6;
  opacity: 2;
}

.sub-menu {
  width: 171px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 44px;
  left: 1px;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity linear 0.15s;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);
  height: 349px;
}

.sub-menu li {
  display: block;
  font-size: .7em;
  color: rgba(135, 135, 135, 1.00);
}

.sub-menu li a {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu li a:hover,
.sub-menu .current-item a {
  background-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, 1.00);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="description" content="Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water Project">
            <title>Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../Xavier website styles.css">
    </head>

<body>
        <div>
        <header>
        <h1><a href="../../Xavier home:portfolio page.html">Xavier King</a></h1>
   </header>

        <div class="menu-wrap">
    <nav class="menu">
      <ul class="clearfix">
          <li><a href="../../Xavier home:portfolio page.html">Portfolio&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li>
                <a>Projects <span class="arrow">▼</span></a>&nbsp;<ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="../freedom/freedom.html">Are We Free?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Ben Hart/Ben Hart.html">Ben Hart</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Daisy Bertenshaw/Daisy Bertenshaw.html">Daisy Bertenshaw</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Decay/Decay.html">Decay</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Earth Wind FIre and Water/Earth, Wind, FIre and Water.html">Earth, Wind, Fire &amp; Water</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../Frozen In Time/Frozen In Time.html">Frozen In Time</a></li>
                    <li><a href="../The CCTV's Eye/The CCTV's Eye.html">The CCTV's Eye</a></li>
              </ul>&nbsp;<li><a href="../../Xavier CV page.html">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;CV&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a></li><li><a href="../../Xavier contact info page.html">&nbsp;Contact</a></li>&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
    <h2>Earth, Wind, Fire, Water</h2>

        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r air.jpg" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Air" />
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y air.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Air"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r air.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Air"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r earth.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Earth"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&r fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; R Fire"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="b&y fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="B &amp; Y Fire"/>
        <img class="mySlides" src="y&r fire.jpg" width="" height="500" alt="Y &amp; R Fire"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you so much, however still having the same problem with the <h2> titles. any advice on how to sort them out?

Comment: sorted out the <h2> but it wont let me position it where I want

Comment: Could you post a JSfiddle of what's happening? Thanks.